# Run a child process free of the parent in Python

Tags: python, process, parent

I have a program I'm running within another. The parent program freezes up while the child process is running. Is there a way to run the child process in the OS as a parent process itself?

Comment: What you want is a separate thread

Comment: When you say you have programs running "within" one another, do you mean one Python script calling another, a Python script launching other programs, a Python script whose functions you want executed in a subprocess, or something else?

Comment: Scott: In Maya (3D app) I'm trying to run an external program. The external program 'locks up' Maya when it is running. I get control of Maya when I close the external/child program. Does that help? Sorry, bit of a newb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects), assuming you're really trying to launch a program that's completely separate from the parent Python script:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["command", "-a", "arg1", "-b", "arg2"])
```

This will launch `command` as a child process of the calling script, without blocking to wait for it to finish. If the parent exits, the child process will continue to run.

Comment: I got this to work outside of a function, but when in a function it doesn't run a detached subprocess.

<code>
import subprocess
def myFunc():
    #do stuff
    subprocess.Popen("C:\myProgram.exe")

myFunc()
</code>

Comment: @john What *does* it do?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have independent processes, please have a look at the `multiprocessing` module. If it is enough to have a separate thread running in the same OS process, then use `threading`. Or are you interested in starting an external program from within a Python script with `subprocess`?

Unfortunately, the terminology is a bit confusing. For example, in Linux "thread" and "process" are both independent processes with no real difference. In python "process" is a separate OS precess, thread runs in the same OS process.

For more information on these, you might have a look at this question: [Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python)