# Child process dies once parent process is restarted/stopped

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a python script -  `script.py`,  that is running as a system service on ubuntu by the name `my.service`. From `script.py`I want to launch another python script called `reset.py` as a separate child process that does some activities and restarts the main service. The problem that I am facing is that whenever the restart command is executed the child script exits prematurely. As per the logging given below, the statement `hello` occurs in the logs but `bellow` never occurs.

The content of `reset.py` is as follows:

```
logging.info("hello")
subprocess.run(["systemctl", "restart", "my.service"])
logging.info("bellow")
```

I have tried `os.fork()`, `nohup` etc from parent program but nothing works. As soon as the service restarts the child process dies. what can I do to ensure that the spawned child keeps executing even after it restarts its parent?

#### Commands tried

1. 

```
command = "nohup" + " " + sys.executable + " " + script_path + " &"
subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

2. 

```
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    command = "nohup" + " " + sys.executable + " " + script_path + " &"
    subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787106/run-a-child-process-free-of-the-parent-in-python

Comment: @Ghoti yes i have read that. I have now edited the question to share what i have tried. It did not work for me